Query regarding MDX CALL statements for stored procedures in Power BI
I wanted to inquire if it is possible to call a stored procedure using the MDX CALL statement in Power BI. Specifically, I would like to know if this approach would enable query folding, thereby improving performance when retrieving data from the database.
Your insights on this matter would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time and assistance.

Yes my data is in the SSAS

As @testing-for-ya commented, you can't use MDX in Power BI. You can either use Power Query or DAX.
In you case, just write the query while importing your data :

